# Is there an "opposite" to the null coalescing operator? (…in any language?)

Tags: c#, programming-languages, syntax, operators, null-coalescing-operator

null coalescing translates roughly to `return x, unless it is null, in which case return y`

I often need `return null if x is null, otherwise return x.y`

I can use `return x == null ? null : x.y;`

Not bad, but that `null` in the middle always bothers me -- it seems superfluous. I'd prefer something like `return x :: x.y;`, where what follows the `::` is evaluated only if what precedes it is not `null`.

I see this as *almost* an opposite to null coalescence, kind of mixed in with a terse, inline null-check, but I'm [*almost*] certain that there is no such operator in C#.

#### Are there other languages that have such an operator? If so, what is it called?

*(I know that I can write a method for it in C#; I use `return NullOrValue.of(x, () => x.y);`, but if you have anything better, I'd like to see that too.)*

Comment: Some have asked for something like x?.y in C#, but nothing like that exists.

Comment: In c++, that would easy enough to express as `return x ? x.y : NULL`. Yay for converting pointer types to booleans!

Comment: @Novelocrat that is one of the things that irritates me most in C# is that they didn't follow the C if that if(anything) = true except when it's if(0, false, null)

Comment: @Chris: that's not an accurate statement about C. If you have a non-scalar variable (such as a struct), you can't use that in a condition.

Comment: If it were implemented, I think a good syntax would be `x ?=> y`: return null if x is null, otherwise return y

Comment: Feature suggestions: `return x == null ? null : Whatever(x);`: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6170791-create-an-anti-null-coalescing-operator  `return x == null ? null : x.Property;`: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3990187-add-operator-to-c

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There's the *null-safe dereferencing operator* (?.) in Groovy... I think that's what you're after.

(It's also called the [safe navigation operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator%28%3F.%29).)

For example:

```
homePostcode = person?.homeAddress?.postcode
```

This will give null if `person`, `person.homeAddress` or `person.homeAddress.postcode` is null.

(This is now [available in C# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) but not in earlier versions)

Comment: Groovy also has the "Elvis operator", which allows default values other than `null`, e.g.: `def bar = foo ?: "<null>"`

Comment: I nominate this feature for C# 5.0. I don't know or care what Groovy actually is, but this is intuitive enough to use in any language.

Comment: It is however being added to C# 6 now, hooray.

Comment: Safe-navigation works for the trivial example posted, but you still need to use the ternary operator if you intend to use the non-null value in a function call, for example: `Decimal? post = pre == null ? null : SomeMethod( pre );`. It would be nice if I could reduce it down to "Decimal? post = pre :: SomeMethod( pre );"

Comment: @Dai: Given the number of permutations you might want of that, I'm happy enough with what we've got.

Answer (score 38):

UPDATE: The requested feature was added to C# 6.0. The original answer from 2010 below should be considered of historical interest only.

---

We considered adding ?. to C# 4. It didn't make the cut; it's a "nice to have" feature, not a "gotta have" feature. We'll consider it again for hypothetical future versions of the language, but I wouldn't hold my breath waiting if I were you. It's not likely to get any more crucial as time goes on. :-)

Comment: Does ease of implementing a feature play into the decision to add it? I ask this because implementing that operator seems like a fairly straight forward, simple addition to the language. I'm no expert (just a recent grad with big love for C#), so please correct me!

Comment: @nick: Sure, implementing the lexer and parser is five minutes work. Then you start worrying about stuff like "does the IntelliSense engine handle it well?" and "how does the error-recovery system deal with it when you've typed the ? but not the . yet?" and just how many different things does "." mean in C# anyway, and how many of them deserve to have a ? before it, and what should the error messages be if you get it wrong, and how much testing is this feature going to need (hint: a lot.) And how are we going to document it and communicate the change, and...

Comment: @nick: To answer your question -- yes, the implementation cost is a factor, but a small one.  There are no cheap features at the level we work at, only more or less expensive features. Five dollars worth of dev work to make the parser work in the correct-code case can easily turn into tens of thousands of dollars worth of design, implementation, testing, documentation and education.

Comment: @EricLippert I think this would be one of MAJOR "nice to have's", which have made C# so successful and also would perfectly serve a mission of making code as concise and expressive as possible!

Comment: I would like to see this added, what I REALLY want is the elvis operator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929836/is-there-an-opposite-to-the-null-coalescing-operator-in-any-language#comment2983361_2929850

Comment: @EricLippert What's the feature in C# 6.0 that would allow an inverse of ??

Comment: @EricLippert I realize this question is old, but nullables are everywhere in our code base. It's like async-await in that regard; it tends to spread. I find myself doing `x is not null ? do() : null` all the time. Would be amazing to get `x ?. do()`.

Comment: @AlexanderHøst: I have not been on the C# team for almost ten years now, so telling me about your feature requests is unlikely to get any results :)  The C# design process is open-sourced; feel free to post a suggestion on their github site if you have a language feature request.

Answer (score 18):

If you've got a special kind of short-circuit boolean logic, you can do this (javascript example):

```
return x && x.y;
```

If `x` is null, then it won't evaluate `x.y`.

Comment: Except this also short-circuits on 0, "" and NaN, so it's not the opposite of ??. It's the opposite of ||.

Answer (score 8):

It just felt right to add this as an answer.

I guess the reason why there is no such thing in C# is because, unlike the coalescing operator (which is only valid for reference types), the reverse operation could yield either a reference or value type (i.e. `class x` with member `int y` - therefore it would unfortunately be unusable in many situations.

I'm not saying, however, that I wouldn't like to see it!

A potential solution to that problem would for the operator to automatically lift a value type expression on the right-hand-side to a nullable.  But then you have the issue that `x.y` where y is an int will actually return an `int?` which would be a pain.

Another, probably better, solution would be for the operator to return the default value (i.e. null or zero) for the type on the right hand side if the expression on the left is null.  But then you have issues distinguishing scenarios where a zero/null was actually read from `x.y` or whether it was supplied by the safe-access operator.

Comment: when I first read the OP's question, this exact issue popped into my head, but I couldn't nail down how to articulate it. It's a very serious problem. +1

Comment: it's not a serious problem. Just use `int?` as the default return value, and the user can change it to an int if he wants. For example if I would like to call some method `Lookup` with a default value of -1 in case one of my references is `null`: `foo?.Bar?.Lookup(baz) ?? -1`

Comment: How about having `?. :` be a ternary operator, where the right-hand side is required to be of the same type as the appropriate member given in the middle?

Answer (score 6):

Delphi has the : (rather than .) operator, which is null-safe.

They were thinking about adding a ?. operator to C# 4.0 to do the same, but that got the chopping block.

[In the meantime, there's IfNotNull()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854591/how-to-check-for-nulls-in-a-deep-lambda-expression/854619#854619) which sort of scratches that itch.  It's certainly larger than ?. or :, but it does let you compose a chain of operations that won't hork a NullReferenceException at you if one of the members is null.

Comment: Can you give an example of using this operator please?

Comment: The `?.` is a C# 6.0 language feature, and yes it does exactly what the OP asked here. Better late than never ^^

Answer (score 4):

In Haskell, you can use the `>>` operator:

- `Nothing >> Nothing` is `Nothing`
- `Nothing >> Just 1` is `Nothing`
- `Just 2 >> Nothing` is `Nothing`
- `Just 2 >> Just 1` is `Just 1`

Answer (score 3):

Haskell has `fmap`, which in this case I think is equivalent to`Data.Maybe.map`. Haskell is purely functional, so what you are looking for would be

```
fmap select_y x
```

If `x` is `Nothing`, this returns `Nothing`.  If `x` is `Just object`, this returns `Just (select_y object)`.  Not as pretty as dot notation, but given that it's a functional language, styles are different.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell let's you reference properties (but not call methods) on a null reference and it will return null if the instance is null. You can do this at any depth. I had hoped that C# 4's dynamic feature would support this but it does not.

```
$x = $null
$result = $x.y  # $result is null

$x = New-Object PSObject
$x | Add-Member NoteProperty y 'test'
$result = $x.y  # $result is 'test'
```

It's not pretty but you could add an extension method that will function the way you describe.

```
public static TResult SafeGet<T, TResult>(this T obj, Func<T, TResult> selector) {
    if (obj == null) { return default(TResult); }
    else { return selector(obj); }
}

var myClass = new MyClass();
var result = myClass.SafeGet(x=>x.SomeProp);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ok<T> {
    T s;
    public static implicit operator ok<T>(T s) { return new ok<T> { s = s }; }
    public static implicit operator T(ok<T> _) { return _.s; }

    public static bool operator true(ok<T> _) { return _.s != null; }
    public static bool operator false(ok<T> _) { return _.s == null; }
    public static ok<T> operator &(ok<T> x, ok<T> y) { return y; }
}
```

I often need this logic for strings:

```
using ok = ok<string>;

...

string bob = null;
string joe = "joe";

string name = (ok)bob && bob.ToUpper();   // name == null, no error thrown
string boss = (ok)joe && joe.ToUpper();   // boss == "JOE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a static instance of your class somewhere with all the right default values for the members.

For example:

```
z = new Thingy { y=null };
```

then instead of your

```
return x != null ? x.y : null;
```

you can write

```
return (x ?? z).y;
```

Comment: I use that technique sometimes (e.g. (x ?? "").ToString()) but it's only practical on a few data types such as PODs and strings.

Answer (score 1):

This is being added in C# vNext (Roslyn powered C#, releases with Visual Studio 2014).

It is called Null propagation and is listed here as complete.
https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status

It is also listed here as complete:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3990187-add-operator-to-c

Answer (score 1):

The so called "null-conditional operator" has been introduced in C# 6.0 and in Visual Basic 14.
In many situations it can be used as the exact opposite of the null-coalescing operator:

```
int? length = customers?.Length; // null if customers is null   
Customer first = customers?[0];  // null if customers is null  
int? count = customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count();  // null if customers, the first customer, or Orders is null
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators