# What is the most concise way to write the opposite of a null coalesce

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an “opposite” to the null coalescing operator? (…in any language?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929836/is-there-an-opposite-to-the-null-coalescing-operator-in-any-language)

Is there a more concise way of writing the third line here?

```
int? i = GetSomeNullableInt();
int? j = GetAnother();
int k = i == null ? i : j;
```

I know of the null coalescing operator but the behaviour I'm looking for is the opposite of this:

```
int k == i ?? j;
```

Comment: Wait a second... why'd you ask a question and then vote to close it as a dupe?

Comment: Because he found the other question. why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sneaky - you edited it while I was replying. :)

I do not believe there is a more concise way of writing that.  However, I would use the "HasValue" property, rather than == null.  Easier to see your intent that way.

```
int? k = !i.HasValue ? i : j;
```

(BTW - k has to be nullable, too.)

Answer (score 1):

In C#, the code you have is the most concise way to write what you want.

Answer (score 1):

What is the point of that operator? The use cases are pretty limited. If you're looking for a single-line solution without having to use a temporary variable, it's not needed in the first place.

```
int k = GetSomeNullableInt() == null ? null : GetAnother();
```