# How to convert objects to strings, but leave null references as null?

Tags: c#

Is there a more concise way of writing

```
string aString = someObj == null ? null : someObj.ToString();
```

i.e. if someObj is a null reference then return a null string, otherwise call ToString() on the object and return that?

Convert.ToString() doesn't help because it returns String.Empty(); I'm passing the result to an XML serializer and I want there to be no element if the object is null, not an empty one.

Comment: See both Jon Skeet and Eric Lippert's answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929836/is-there-an-opposite-to-the-null-coalescing-operator-in-any-language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such C# feature but **probably it will be** and can be called **monadic null checking** with `?.` syntax, as described in [probable C# 6.0 features](http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated) article:

```
string aString = someObj?.ToString();
```

Comment: Accepting this answer as it tells the truth of the current situation while offering hope for a brighter future to come :-)

Answer (score 7):

Your code is pretty simple. If you wish to reduce the amount of code because you must write the same fragment a lot of times, you could put the code into an extension method:

```
static class SomeObjExtensions {
    public static string ToStringWithNull(this object someObj) {
        return someObj == null ? null : someObj.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wondering if `ToStringOrNull` conveys the meaning better?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension method that describes the action,

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static string ToStringOrNull(this object o)
    {
        return o == null ? null : o.ToString();
    }
}
```

And use it as,

```
var aString = o.ToStringOrNull();
```

Answer (score -4):

```
if(someObject == null) {
return null;
} else {
return someObject.ToString();
}
```

Yours is concise as it can get.