# Ignore the column in lambda when value is null

Tags: c#, lambda

I am having list of object in which there are null values available in the list. If I want to filter based on few columns in that list using lambda. In this case I have to exclude the filter condition when there is a column comes with null value.

Ex: _db.test.select(x=>x.value1==a && value2==b).tolist();

In this example let's assume value1 has null value. At that time I don't want to use value1 for the condition. I have to eliminate value1 condition. I can go with rest of the conditions available in the lambda expression.

Comment: You mean like `((x.value1 == null || x.value1 == a) && value2 == b)`?

Comment: By the way, `.Select` isn't a filter, it's a projection. The result of your code would be a `List<bool>`.

Comment: Visit here   https://stackoverflow.com/a/854619/7300644

Answer (score 1):

```cs
enumerable.Where( x => ( x.value1 == null || x.value1 == a ) && x.value2 == b )
```

or

```cs
enumerable
.Where( x => x.value1 == null || x.value1 == a )
.Where( x => x.value2 == b )
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside Select() you can't set condition
you must use Where();
`Ex: _db.test.Where(x=>x.value1==a && value2==b).tolist();`